# Is Pageant applying the entered passphrase too few keys in a row on purpose?

Tags: ssh, pageant

[In another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/500845/is-using-the-one-passphrase-for-many-keys-safe) I asked about passphrases and the mechanism against being compromised in the case of a huge amount of sample data.

What brought me here is Pageant, which remembers the passphrase entered on the one key and applies it to the other key. So, if I have two keys with the same passphrase in Pageant I have to enter the passphrase once - is it desired behavior?

Comment: Please define "desired". Desired by whom?

Comment: Desired by the Pageant creators.